Free Community edision - Attaching xlsx file to docx word document
We have a requirement to attach a xlsx file to docx document or attaching a file while creating docx document. Does free docx4j community edition support this feature.
As of now we are exploring feature set of docx4j and we are pursuing docx4j community edition.

Does it support it ?  Yes
Will they hold your hand?  No.
Can you Pay for Plutext to use their hand holding version? Yes.

yes thats right , we need to pay Plutext for the hand holding version.

Reply from doc4xj support
You can certainly write code to do this using docx4j, however there are no high level convenience methods to assist you.
In contrast, Plutext's Enterprise product contains an OLE Helper component to assist you with embedding objects.
If you want to write the code from scratch, you should create a sample docx in Word and examine it carefully. You can use the code generation tools to generate code from your sample docx, which will get you part of the way there. That said, it would certainly be a lot easier to try the Enterprise product.
